# I am getting a Multiplicity constraint violation error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to query some data using EF and I wrote this EF query. Saying I have a Multiplicity contraint betwen KPMUnitPaypoint_KPMPaypoint_source I am just lost on what I need to do to fix this. I ran the code without the last select from the model and it runs as expected. I just want to set those items to those fields and I am getting the error.

```
var enumerable = DataServiceLocator.GetKPMUnitPaypoints_DAO()
    .GetKPMUnitPaypointsByProjectID(project_id, Context)
        .Where(x => x.CompletionDate.HasValue && x.CompletionDate >= datefrom && x.CompletionDate <= dateto || 
            (x.AccruedDate.HasValue && x.AccruedDate >= datefrom && x.AccruedDate <= dateto) ||
            (show == "PENDING") && 
            (x.KPMPaypoint.TradePhase.Trade.Proper_Trade_Name == service || service == "ALL") && 
            (x.KPMPaypoint.TradePhase.Phase_Name == phase || phase == "ALL") && 
            (!x.ApprovedBy.HasValue && show == "PENDING") || 
            (x.Accrued.HasValue && show == "ACCRUED") || 
            (x.AccruedDate.HasValue && x.Accrued.HasValue && show == "ACCRUED-APPROVED") ||
            (show == "ALL" && x.Active))
        .Select(x => new KPMPaypointByUnitDetailModel
        {
            Completed_By = Context.Employee.Where(p => p.Employee_ID == x.CompletionUser).FirstOrDefault().UserName,
            Completed_Date = x.CompletionDate,
            Description = x.KPMPaypoint.Description,
            Vendor_Name = Context.KPMVistaVendors.Where(p => p.Vista_Vendor_ID == x.VistaVendorID).FirstOrDefault().Vista_Vendor_Name,
            Amount = x.Amount,
            Unit_Code = x.KPMUnit.UnitType.Code,
            Unit_Type = x.KPMUnit.UnitType.Name,
            Approved = x.Approved,
            Approved_By = Context.Employee.Where(p => p.Employee_ID == x.ApprovedBy).FirstOrDefault().UserName,
            Approved_Date = x.ApprovedDate,
            Trade = x.KPMPaypoint.TradePhase.Trade.Proper_Trade_Name,
            Phase = x.KPMPaypoint.TradePhase.Phase_Name,
            Accrued = x.Accrued,
            Accrued_Date = x.AccruedDate,
            Accrued_User = Context.Employee.Where(p => p.Employee_ID == x.AccruedBy).FirstOrDefault().UserName
        }).ToList().AsEnumerable();
```

unitpaypoint entity:

```
namespace KMSEntities
{
    public class KPMUnitPaypoints
    {
        public int UnitPaypointID { get; set; }

        public int UnitID { get; set; }

        public int PayPointID { get; set; }

        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        public bool Billable { get; set; }

        public decimal? SubPayAmount { get; set; }

        public DateTime? CompletionDate { get; set; }

        public int? CompletionUser { get; set; }

        public  int? VistaVendorID { get; set; }

        public bool? Approved { get; set; }

        public int? ApprovedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? ApprovedDate { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public bool? Accrued { get; set; }

        public DateTime? AccruedDate { get; set; }

        public int? AccruedBy { get; set; }

        public int? ContractItem { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PayPointID")]
        public virtual KPMPaypoint KPMPaypoint { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UnitID")]
        public KPMUnits KPMUnit { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

paypoint entity:

```
public class KPMPaypoint
{
    public KPMPaypoint()
    {
        KPMUnitPaypoints = new HashSet<KPMUnitPaypoints>();
    }

    public int PaypointID { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TP_ID")]
    public TradePhase TradePhase { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int TP_ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<KPMUnitPaypoints> KPMUnitPaypoints { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure how to get around this error, here are my models.

Comment: Please post the error, full exception and stack....

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'KPMUnitPaypoints_KPMPaypoint_Source' of the relationship 'KMSDataAccess.KPMUnitPaypoints_KPMPaypoint' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>